# How to assign "cout" to another object of ostream class?

Tags: c++, c++17

My code

```
std::ostream a = std::cout;
```

throws the following error:

> ```
> "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>
>  ::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits> &) 
>  [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" 
> (declared at line 404 of "/usr/include/c++/11/ostream") is inaccessible
> ```

How does changing it to `std::ostream& a = std::cout;` fix it?

Comment: A stream cannot be copied but this is what `std::ostream a = std::cout;` requires to do. Maybe, you intended to do `std::ostream& a = std::cout;` which means to init. a reference `a` to `std::cout`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't reassign the whole stream, but you can swap out the underlying buffer using [`rdbuf()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/)

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::ostringstream alternative; // get an alternative stream
std::streambuf* original = std::cout.rdbuf();  // remember the original cout buffer
std::cout.rdbuf(alternative.rdbuf()); // replace cout buffer with string buffer

doSomething();

std::cout.rdbuf(original); // restore original buffer
```

[Try it online [Godbolt]](https://godbolt.org/z/fErvTKxf3)

Answer (score 2):

If I have a look into my crystal ball I think you might be attempting to have a reference to an ostream where it might be `std::cout`  or where it might be an actual file `ofstream` object. In that case you can use a pointer as an intermediary, while the decision is being made.

```
int main(){
    // default is std::cout
    std::ostream* os = &std::cout;
    if(do_i_want_os_as_a_file){
         // mind the lifetime of this object if you care.
         os = new std::ofstream(FILENAME); 
    }
    std::ostream& out = *os;
    // your outputs are now
    out << "Hello there\n";
}
```

I think this is neater/clearer than swapping the underlying buffer.

Comment: I like this better too.  But if working with other code outside of one's own control that is using `std::cout` (rather than being passed in a `std::ostream&` like I'd rather have seen), then Thomas's approach may be a reasonable alternative in the interim.